# How to backup Firebase Realtime Database more frequently than once in 24 hours?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to find a solution for this since a couple of days now. I want to backup my data of Realtime Database more frequently than what is provided by Firebase i.e. once in 24 hours. I have done a similar thing with my FireStore, deployed an app and a cron job to backup every 8 hours and save that to my GS bucket. But I couldn't find anything at all which is a similar for Realtime Database.

Here's what I have tried-

I am using firebase functions here (I will add a cron job later). What I am doing is fetching every child of my db's root node and zipping it with zlib. Here's what my code looks like-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const zlib = require('zlib');

exports.backup = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

cors(request, response, async () => {
    const db = admin.database();
    const ref_deb = db.ref("/");
    ref_deb.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log("Database value " + snapshot.val());
        let jsonFileContent = snapshot.val();
        if (jsonFileContent != null) {
            //console.log(io);
            console.log("getCompressedJSONFile function started", jsonFileContent);
            let bufferObject = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonFileContent));
            zlib.gzip(bufferObject, function (err, zippedData) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error in gzip compression using zlib module", err);
                    response.send("Error").status(500);
                } else {
                    console.log("zippedData", zippedData);
                    response.send(zippedData).status(200);
                }
            })
        } else {
            response.send("Error").status(500)
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
});
```

I am getting the response (obviously encoded and not readable)
[image]

Now I want to **upload it to my GS bucket**. How can I do that? Is it possible to do it by passing the zippedContents from zlib without creating a file? Any help will be appreciated.

**My database is less than 0.5 MB uncompressed so backing everything at once shouldn't be an issue.**

Answer (score 0):

There is many questions in your question.

First, you can't trigger manually a backup like you can do it into Firestore (Firebase).

Then, you can stream directly your file from your function to storage, but I don't recommend it. Indeed, there is no CRC when you stream data, and, if an issue occur in your ZIP file, the whole file is corrupted and you can't recover your data

If your file is small, I recommend you to store it into `/tmp` directory, a writable in-memory file system (tmpfs), and then copy the file to the bucket.

Comment: I think that there might be a confusion because **you can** trigger a manual backup for the realtime db but not for Firestore.

 I was thinking about creating a file and storing it in the temp directory but I couldn't find any useful article or documentation containing the compression of the JSON file. Can you point me to any article that I might have missed?

Comment: Can you point me where you can trigger manual export with realtime database? {Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) the feature available on Firestore. Anyway, for your compression question, I recommend you to define a format in your file. If it's JSON, use JSONL format with 1 full json object per line (not indented). Then, it's easy to stream compress your file each time that you add a line. I usually also do this with GZip. It works well.